# Using an allocated and initialised object outside of viewDidLoad?

Tags: objective-c, instances

*I hope the question title is adequate*

Just confused about something in a piece of code I have seen in an online tutorial. There is a generic `ZHEDog` class with declared properties, methods, etc. and from this class we have created several instances - firstDog, secondDog, fourthDog, and so on.

Now, when we created each instance we did so inside of the viewDidLoad method of our main(one)view controller with the line:

```
ZHEDog *fourthDog = [[ZHEDog alloc] init];
```

and then we set some of its properties like name, and so on, here after this line.

So we did this instance creation in the view controller's viewDidLoad and so far have not subclassed the generic ZHEDog class, so it is all deriving from the one class file.

Now, where I am confused is that apparently I cannot set a property of this instance in another method (other than `viewDidLoad`), so I can't say something like:

```
-(void) printHelloWorld
{
fourthDog.name = "something new";
}
```

It kind of makes sense but I can't explain why. I would have thought once the instance was allocated and initialised I could change its properties where I wanted to if necessary? But do the same rules of scope apply to viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use properties, they are like instance variables accessible from everywhere within the instance of the class

```
@property ZHEDog *firstDog, *fourthDog;
```

then instantiate them in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.firstDog = [[ZHEDog alloc] init];
self.fourthDog = [[ZHEDog alloc] init];
```

and change them in a method

```
-(void) printHelloWorld
{
self.firstDog.name = "woof";       
self.fourthDog.name = "something new";
}
```

Comment: Thanks vadian - I had imagined an alloced and inited object as having some kind of super power when in fact it is bound by normal rules of scope.. I have no idea why I thought it had a special licence to be called outside of its method scope. Thanks for pointing that out re properties, very helpful.

Comment: Vadian, just as a related question - if you do use properties, is it okay to initialise them at the beginning of your @implementation section, as in, on top of viewDidLoad? Or do you have to have this in viewDidLoad?

Comment: in Objective-C all properties are set to a default value of `nil` for objects and `0` / `false` for scalar types. If you want custom default values, you have to set them overriding the `init` method of the class. In any case you have to initialize the instance `…dog` before using its properties.

Comment: Thanks again but where is it okay to initialise the instances apart from viewDidLoad, even when they are properties?

Comment: create them wherever you want, but anyway before using them

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does creating them in viewDidLoad just make sure that they get alloced and inited when the program is run?

Answer (score 1):

What @vadian has is correct, but using properties also allows other classes to see this variable. Say if you imported the header file and it contained `@property ZHEDog *firstDog, *fourthDog;`. These variables become public. unless they're in the implantation file.

But other approach is creating variables like so:

**Header File**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    ZHEDog *firstDog, *fourthDog;

}

@end
```

All will be the same expect now the values are private, or exclusive, to just the ViewController. therefore not allowing others to use or see these variables. And to access the variables in your function **printHelloWorld**:

```
- (void)printHelloWorld {
    firstDog.name = @"woof";       
    fourthDog.name = @"something new";

}
```

**Allocating**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //new is the combination of alloc and init. only use +new when using alloc and init, not alloc and initWith...
    firstDog = [ZHEDog new];
    fourthDog = [ZHEDog new];

}
```

i hope this would better your goal :)

Comment: Using instance variables rather than properties requires implementation of getter and setter methods

Comment: True :3 having setters and getters allow access to these variables outside the class. is it not required when you're only using the variables from within the class and no where else?

Comment: the OP wants to access the variables outside the class ;-)

Comment: Oh, thought it was just an *out of scope* deal. Yes I understand using properties in the ZHEDog class was perfect, hands down

Comment: @vadian can I just ask about the question that user1967709 brought up: if I were to only need to use the ivars in the one file, would writing out setters and getters be unnecessary?

Comment: setter and getter are unnecessary when you use the variables in the `ZHEDog` class implementation file

Comment: @vadian And are they still unnecessary if you declare the ivars in the view controller interface, and use the variables in the view controller implementation file? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: variables of a specific class must always declared within that class. Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html